# Can't create/write to file '/path/file.csv' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Tags: mysql, debian

I want to put the result of my query in a file csv but it shows me this error. I change access rights but same mistakeIdeas please

```
SELECT id, filename
INTO OUTFILE '/home/results.csv'
FROM attachments
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to the `/home` directory, which you can only do as root. This directory is intended to contain all the users' home directories, named with the corresponding username.

So, you should change the output path to e.g. `/home/<username>/results.csv`, or to some other path you have write access to.

Comment: Even if / home is made for that the fact that I changed the right of access should solve the problem. it's the same mistake I changed directory "/ home / user / desktop"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux,

```
SELECT id, filename
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/results.csv'
FROM attachments
```

and find the csv file /tmp